# How to enable status bar in KIOSK mode for 7.0 device?

Tags: android-management-api, android-managed-profile

I have been developing a KIOSK application where i am unable to enable status bar for devices running OS 7.0 or below. I have enabled all the settings in my policy e.g.

```
 "statusBarDisabled": false,
 "kioskCustomization": {
    "powerButtonActions": "POWER_BUTTON_AVAILABLE",
    "systemErrorWarnings": "ERROR_AND_WARNINGS_ENABLED",
    "systemNavigation": "NAVIGATION_ENABLED",
    "statusBar": "NOTIFICATIONS_AND_SYSTEM_INFO_ENABLED",
    "deviceSettings": "SETTINGS_ACCESS_ALLOWED"
  }
```

but the status bar is still disabled and i am unable to see the battery and time information. However, the same settings are working perfectly fine for devices running OS 8.0 or above.

Help appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

“statusBarDisabled” is already deprecated, you can remove it on your policy. Unfortunately, [statusBar](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#statusbar) isn't supported for 7.0 devices. It's only supported from API level 28 (aka Android 9 / Android Pie). You may refer to [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#setLockTaskFeatures(android.content.ComponentName,%20int)) for more information about this.